# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Not able to find libmlpack-dev

Tags: software-installation, boost

In github of mlpack, it is mentioned I can install using apt-get, but I get unable to locate package error for libmlpack-dev.

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install `libmlpack-dev` for Ubuntu 14.04 from the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~titas-chanda/+archive/ubuntu/armadillo. In case it is not obvious that the PPA does indeed contain the `libmlpack-dev` package, see https://launchpad.net/~titas-chanda/+archive/ubuntu/armadillo/+sourcepub/6312138/+listing-archive-extra.

To install `libmlpack-dev` using this PPA, do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:titas-chanda/armadillo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libmlpack-dev
```

Comment: Hey, I have installed through the ppa, but I am not able to find the libmlpack.so file in usr/lib or usr/local/lib

Comment: @user2761431 Hmm, that is surprising. I didn't try to build `mlpack` from source myself, so I can't debug on my end. Maybe ask a new question if you still can't figure it out?

Comment: @user2761431 It might be in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.